# Why is my Bootstrap navbar dropdown not displaying?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, navigation, navbar, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make a Bootstrap navbar that will display the items that can be seen in the code. All of my other links work and take me to their respected pages, but whenever I hit the dropdown in the navbar nothing happens. It is the dropdown portion that I can not get to work and I am not sure what else I need to add. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is Bootstrap5

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #4f2fb6;">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">GCU</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>  
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="tando.html">Course Matrix</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="media.html">Media</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Topics
              </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#topic1" data-bs-toggle="collapse">Topic 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#topic2" data-bs-toggle="collapse">Topic 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#topic3" data-bs-toggle="collapse">Topic 3</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#topic4" data-bs-toggle="collapse">Topic 4</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#topic5" data-bs-toggle="collapse">Topic 5</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#topic6" data-bs-toggle="collapse">Topic 6</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#topic7" data-bs-toggle="collapse">Topic 7</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Did you include Bootstrap JavaScript plugins or bundle in your HTML file?

Comment: I did, and I am using the latest version of Bootstrap. Even when I copy and paste the simplest examples I can find of a dropdown they still do not work.

Comment: With Bootstrap CSS and JS included I can't reproduce your problem. This [pen](https://codepen.io/tromgy/pen/WNZQpGm) shows it working.

Comment: can you share the plugins you are using because I am getting mine straight from the Bootstrap website, but there might be a problem with it I do not realize.

Comment: It's all in that pen. CSS is included like this: `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">` and JS is : `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: You do have two `</button>` at the end of `navbar-toggler`. Not sure if this creates a huge problem but it might.

Comment: @JonathonDuranJr. The links inside dropdown are anchor links. Are you sure you have elements with that respective id in your page?